# convert QVideoFrame to QImage

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I want to get every frames from a `QMediaPlayer` and convert it to `QImage` (or `cv::Mat`)

so I used   `videoFrameProbed` signal from `QVideoProbe`:

```
connect(&video_probe_, &QVideoProbe::videoFrameProbed, 
         [this](const QVideoFrame& currentFrame){
   //QImage img = ??
}
```

But I didn't find any way for getting `QImage` from `QVideoFrame`!

How can I convert `QVideoFrame` to `QImage` ?!

Comment: That depends on the format of the QVideoFrame. QImage can only accept [a couple of RGB-based formats](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#image-formats). There are various libraries that can convert between various YUV and RGB formats. But if you can I'd recommend reading your video frames with OpenCV directly.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 12):

You can use QImage's constructor:

```
 QImage img( currentFrame.bits(),
             currentFrame.width(),
             currentFrame.height(),
             currentFrame.bytesPerLine(),
             imageFormat);
```

Where you can get `imageFormat` from `pixelFormat` of the `QVideoFrame`:

```
 QImage::Format imageFormat = QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(currentFrame.pixelFormat());
```

Comment: though the video is likely in YUV format (imageFormatFromPixelFormat will fail).  Not sure if Qt has yuv conversion built in.. alternatively could use libyuv.

Comment: I think Qt relies on underlying mediaframework for conversions. On Linux that is gstreamer which supports a lot of conversions. As a supporting fact, in custom implementations of QAbstractVideoSurface you are forced to implement pure virtual supportedPixelFormats, and when I specified BGR24 as the only format that is the format I received.

Comment: Please also read requirements here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html#details for QVideoFrame to call map() before calling bits()

Comment: I tried, then img.save("filename.png"), but there are not output.

Answer (score 8):

For QCamera output, that method doesn't always work. In particular, QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat() returns QImage::Format_Invalid when given QVideoFrame::Format_Jpeg, which is what's coming out of my QCamera. But this works:

```
QImage Camera::imageFromVideoFrame(const QVideoFrame& buffer) const
{
    QImage img;
    QVideoFrame frame(buffer);  // make a copy we can call map (non-const) on
    frame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);
    QImage::Format imageFormat = QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(
                frame.pixelFormat());
    // BUT the frame.pixelFormat() is QVideoFrame::Format_Jpeg, and this is
    // mapped to QImage::Format_Invalid by
    // QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat
    if (imageFormat != QImage::Format_Invalid) {
        img = QImage(frame.bits(),
                     frame.width(),
                     frame.height(),
                     // frame.bytesPerLine(),
                     imageFormat);
    } else {
        // e.g. JPEG
        int nbytes = frame.mappedBytes();
        img = QImage::fromData(frame.bits(), nbytes);
    }
    frame.unmap();
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Qt has a private function `qt_imageFromVideoFrame` for converting `QVideoFrame` to `QImage`. If you want to use it, you'll need to:

1. Add `QT += multimedia multimedia-private` to your `.pro` file
2. Add `#include "private/qvideoframe_p.h"` to your `.cpp` file
3. Then you can use `qt_imageFromVideoFrame` with the following signature:

   QImage qt_imageFromVideoFrame( const QVideoFrame& f );

Be aware of the warning in the header:

```
//
//  W A R N I N G
//  -------------
//
// This file is not part of the Qt API.  It exists purely as an
// implementation detail.  This header file may change from version to
// version without notice, or even be removed.
//
// We mean it.
//
```

The implementation uses `QVideoFrame::map()` and does low-level manipulation with the bits. The converters handle a variety of conditions including YUV.

The `qt_imageFromVideoFrame` works on almost all platforms.
i.e. Windows, macOS, Linux and iOS.
The only platform it doesn't work reliably well is Android.
There, you'll need to use OpenGL calls to extract the VideoFrame. Also, on Android, you need to call `QImage:rgbSwapped()` at the end because QImage stores images as ARGB whereas OpenGL retrieves them as ABGR.

```
QImage QVideoFrameToQImage( const QVideoFrame& videoFrame )
{
    if ( videoFrame.handleType() == QAbstractVideoBuffer::NoHandle )
    {
        QImage image = qt_imageFromVideoFrame( videoFrame );
        if ( image.isNull() ) return QImage();
        if ( image.format() != QImage::Format_ARGB32 ) return image.convertToFormat( QImage::Format_ARGB32 );
        return image;
    }
    if ( videoFrame.handleType() == QAbstractVideoBuffer::GLTextureHandle )
    {
        QImage image( videoFrame.width(), videoFrame.height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32 );
        GLuint textureId = static_cast<GLuint>( videoFrame.handle().toInt() );
        QOpenGLContext* ctx = QOpenGLContext::currentContext();
        QOpenGLFunctions* f = ctx->functions();
        GLuint fbo;
        f->glGenFramebuffers( 1, &fbo );
        GLint prevFbo;
        f->glGetIntegerv( GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &prevFbo );
        f->glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo );
        f->glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,  GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0 );
        f->glReadPixels( 0, 0,  videoFrame.width(),  videoFrame.height(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.bits() );
        f->glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, static_cast<GLuint>( prevFbo ) );
        return image.rgbSwapped();
    }
    return QImage();
}
```

I have a complete working app on GitHub that includes an implementation of the above function:

https://github.com/stephenquan/MyVideoFilterApp/blob/master/QVideoFrameToQImage.cpp

Answer (score 2):

For anyone ending up here after finding that the qt private function "qt_imageFromVideoFrame" no longer exists in Qt5.15.0, you can now use the newly implemented method QImage QVideoFrame::image().

```
QImage img = frame.image();
```

I've tested this on Ubuntu and it works.

For Ubuntu version 6.4 use:
`QImage img = frame.toImage();`

Comment: Thanks, you save life, hope it works on android too